# Oracle sql Select the first and last name of the customer with most orders in 2017

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following tables

f_orders

```
ORDER_NUMBER    NUMBER(5,0)
ORDER_DATE      DATE
ORDER_TOTAL     NUMBER(8,2)
CUST_ID         NUMBER(5,0)
STAFF_ID        NUMBER(5,0)
```

with the following data

```
  ORDER_NUMBER  ORDER_DATE  ORDER_TOTAL CUST_ID STAFF_ID
    5678         10-Dec-2017    103.02     123    12
    9999         10-Dec-2017       10      456    19
    9997         09-Dec-2017       3       123    19
    9989         10-Dec-2016       3       123    19
```

and

f_customers

```
ID          NUMBER(5,0) 
FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(25)    
LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(35)    
ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(50)
```

with the following data

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   ADDRESS
123     Cole       Bee    123 Main Street
456      Zoe       Twee   1009 Oliver Avenue
```

I'm supposed to display the name of the customer wthi the most orders placed in the year 2017.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT f_customers.first_name, 
       f_customers.last_name, 
       count(order_total)
FROM f_orders JOIN f_customers 
ON f_customers.id = f_orders.CUST_ID
WHERE TO_CHAR(order_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') LIKE '%2017'
GROUP BY f_customers.first_name,  f_customers.last_name
HAVING count(order_total) = (SELECT max(count(cust_id)) 
                             FROM f_orders 
                             GROUP BY cust_id)
```

The problem is that whenever I insert the where statement it returns `no data found`, even though it should return the name Cole Bee with 2 orders
If I remove the where statement it will show that Cole Bee has placed 3 orders

I can't figure out why I get the `no data found` result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main query is filtering on the year; the subquery on the right hand side of the `having` clause is not. The `max(count())` is 3 if you run that subquery on its own, and you’re comparing that with the filtered list which (as you expect) only finds 2 rows for that customer.

Run the whole query with just the `having` part removed (rather than the `where` clause), and run *just* the subquery; and compare the results.

The simple answer is to repeat the filter:

```
SELECT f_customers.first_name, 
       f_customers.last_name, 
       count(order_total)
FROM f_orders JOIN f_customers 
ON f_customers.id = f_orders.CUST_ID
WHERE TO_CHAR(order_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') LIKE '%2017'
GROUP BY f_customers.first_name,  f_customers.last_name
HAVING count(order_total) = (SELECT max(count(cust_id)) 
                             FROM f_orders 
                             WHERE TO_CHAR(order_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') LIKE '%2017'
                             GROUP BY cust_id)
```

Both filters could be written more simply as:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(order_date, 'YYYY') = '2017'
```

or even:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 2017
```

You can avoid hitting the table twice using analytic queries and other tricks but as this seems to be an assignment that may be getting beyond what you’ve been taught and are expected to know/use.